# What is the correct place to add a database driven scheduler in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, startup

I have added a `Timer` to `Startup` class of an `ASP.Net Core` application. It fires on some time period and do operations like logging a sample text. I need it to be able to do database driven operations like adding a record to a table. So I try to get `AppDbContext` from DI but it is always null. Please see the code:

```
    public class Scheduler
{
    static Timer _timer;
    static bool _isStarted;
    static ILogger<Scheduler> _logger;
    const int dueTimeMin = 1;
    const int periodMin = 1;

    public static void Start(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_isStarted)
            throw new Exception("Currently is started");

        _logger = (ILogger<Scheduler>)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<Scheduler>));

        var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var operationClass = new OperationClass(serviceProvider);
        _timer = new Timer(operationClass.DoOperation, autoEvent, dueTimeMin * 60 * 1000, periodMin * 60 * 1000);
        _isStarted = true;
        _logger.LogInformation("Scheduler started");            
    }
}

public class OperationClass
{
    IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    ILogger<OperationClass> _logger;
    AppDbContext _appDbContext;

    public OperationClass(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = (ILogger<OperationClass>)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<OperationClass>));
        _appDbContext = (AppDbContext)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(AppDbContext));
    }

    public void DoOperation(Object stateInfo)
    {
        try     
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timer elapsed.");

            if (_appDbContext == null)
                throw new Exception("appDbContext is null");

            _appDbContext.PlayNows.Add(new PlayNow
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now
            });

            _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error in DoOperation: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

And here it is the code from `Startup`:

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        AppHelper.InitializeMapper();
        Scheduler.Start(serviceProvider);
    }
```

I guess I am calling `Scheduler.Start` in a wrong place. Seems that `AppDbContext` is not ready yet.

What is the correct place to call `Scheduler.Start`?

Comment: Yes you are calling it too early in the startup flow. The service provider wont be properly configured till after `ConfigureServices` has been called. So I suggest you look there after you have added the db context. I would also suggest making the scheduler a service with explicit dependencies and have it in the service collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are running code on a background thread, you should always begin a new 'scope' for your DI container on that background thread and resolve from that scope.

So what you should do is:

- Create a new scope inside the event
- Resolve `OperationClass` from that scope
- Inside `OperationClass` only rely on *constructor injection*; not on [Service Location](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    static Timer _timer;
    const int dueTimeMin = 1;
    const int periodMin = 1;

    public static void Start(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        if (scopeFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("scopeFactory");
        _timer = new Timer(_ =>
        {
            using (var scope = new scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                scope.GetRequiredService<OperationClass>().DoOperation();
            }
        }, new AutoResetEvent(false), dueTimeMin * 60 * 1000, periodMin * 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Here `Start` depends on `IServiceScopeFactory`. `IServiceScopeFactory` can be resolved from the `IServiceProvider`.

Your `OperationClass` will becomes something like the following:

```
public class OperationClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<OperationClass> _logger;
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

    public OperationClass(ILogger<OperationClass> logger, AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        if (appDbContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appDbContext));

        _logger = logger;
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    public void DoOperation()
    {
        try     
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("DoOperation.");

            _appDbContext.PlayNows.Add(new PlayNow
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now
            });

            _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error in DoOperation: {exception}");
        }
    }
}
```

Although not documentation particular to the .NET Core Container, [this documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/howto+multi-threading) provides a more detailed information about how to work with a DI Container in a multi-threaded application.

Comment: thank for your descriptive answer. Where should I call `        Scheduler.Start()`?

Comment: @Afshar: You should call `Start` somewhere in your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Your `Startup` method seems an obious place.

Answer (score 3):

You should call it inside `ConfigureServices` after your `AppDbContext` has been resolved, in the code you are calling it before DI registrations. also you can use `services.BuildServiceProvider()` to create an `IServiceProvider` containing services from the provided DI:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    MmHelper.InitializeMapper();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // ....

    Scheduler.Start(services.BuildServiceProvider());
}
```